# awk: line 1: syntax error at or near {

Tags: bash, awk

I have been trying to get a maximum and a minimum value in the text file that have a numerical table. In order to do this, I opened up each column in the file using **awk** function **for loop**. But I got this error below. I am beginner to use awk, and I cannot find what the problem is. Please help me out!

I got stuck in this problem with:

```
awk: line 1 : syntax error at or near {
awk: line 1 : syntax error at or near }
awk: line 1 : syntax error at or near {
awk: line 1 : syntax error at or near }
```

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..11}
do
    #print minimum value in the text file.
    awk -F' ' '{print ${i}}' [filename].txt | sort -n | head -1
    #print maximum value in the text file.
    awk -F' ' '{print ${i}}' [filename].txt | sort -n | tail -1
done
```

Comment: `${1}` is not correct. Use `$1` instead. I am not sure what you mean with `[filename]`, by the way. It's syntactically correct, but it resolves either to a list of files with single-character names `a`, `e`, `f`, `i`, `l`, `m` or `n`, or to the literal string `[filename]`; none of which is likely to be your intention.

Comment: You could also use `sort -n $filename | head -1 | cut -f1 -d' '`. Or use `awk`'s processing power for finding the maximum and minimum in one pass without `head`, `tail` and `sort`.

Comment: Why are you trying to reference $NF in the BASH part of the script?  It rather looks like you are trying to loop through awk-parsed items outside the awk script.  awk variables are completely separate from BASH variables.

Comment: Another oddity: You loop $NF times, and in each loop you do exactly the same thing. You get the same output $NF times. As @kbulgrien says, you seem to be mixing Bash and `awk`. What does an input file look like?

Comment: `{1..$NF}` is a literal not a sequence

Comment: [Filename] is a just filename such as *.txt.

Comment: `*.txt` isn't a filename. It's a glob that may or may not match one or more filenames. If your code refers to a single file I'd put a single file in there, e.g. `example.txt`

Comment: I made a mistake in my question: not {1}, but {i}.

Comment: Ok. Great comment. I edit my code on my question.

Comment: My input file is a table 10 by 11 that have numerical values.

Comment: Ok. If do not use $NF but use just number, is it correct?

Comment: Berndbausch. How can I use awk to find both max and min in the table text file?

Comment: @ChangwanSun by looping through all numbers and keeping the largest and the smallest. If it's a matrix: `awk 'NR==1 { min=max=$1} { for (i=1;i<=NF; i++) { if ($i>max) max=$i; if ($i<min) min=$i } } END {print min, max}'`. Not tested.

Comment: ${i} is also incorrect awk syntax.

Comment: My awk program initializes both `min` and `max` to the first number in the first line. Then, in each line, it loops over all fields, adjusting `min` and `max` in the process.

Comment: Your mixing shell and awk (2 completely different tools/languages) syntax, semantics, and variable scope. Please [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can best help you. It's not clear if you're trying to find the min/max in each field, each row, each column, across the whole file or something else, nor is it obvious what you want the output to look like.

Answer (score 3):

Given the structure of your shell script, I’m assuming you want to determine the minimum and maximum per column. This can be done entirely in AWK:

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { delete mins; delete maxs }
{
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    if (!(i in mins) || $i < mins[i]) mins[i] = $i
    if (!(i in maxs) || $i > maxs[i]) maxs[i] = $i
  }
}
END {
  for (i = 1; i in mins; i++) printf("%d ", mins[i])
  print ""
  for (i = 1; i in maxs; i++) printf("%d ", maxs[i])
  print ""
}
```

The `BEGIN` lines initialises the empty arrays.

The second block processes each line, and within each line, each field. We check the current index against the arrays’ keys; if we haven’t yet stored a value, or if the value is smaller (for minima) or larger (for maxima) than the stored value, we update the value in the array.

The `END` block displays the result, looping over indexes.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn’t thought of checking the keys... I wanted to avoid referring to `NF` in the `END` section to allow for varying numbers of fields in each line.

Comment: Ah, I see, then yeah what you have now is the way to do it.